# C3.js integration with React.js for real time data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, c3.js

I am looking at c3.js integration with reactjs for real time data which is coming through server side events. This is what I have so far :

https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/15384/

C3js has flow API which can be used to render part of graphs (http://c3js.org/samples/api_flow.html) for new incoming data.

However I believe using that API would actually directly manipulate the DOM instead of using the virtual DOM concept of react. Any idea/suggestion of possible workaround.

I looked into existing NPM modules but couldn't find one that can support the use case.

Actually I want to transform graphs from one to another (which is very well supported through C3 API). C3 js is based on d3 js. I understand that d3 js binding with react is far better but what I need is better available through C3.

Also in current code I am using `bindto: '#chart_1',` which again manipulates the DOM directly. I don't think this is the best way to render the graph. Any thoughts on that too are appreciated.

Code:

```
var getDataFromStores = function() {  
  return [{
            "proxy" : "10.0.1.15:1211",
            "url" : "http://www.google.com/in/test",
            "host" : "http://www.google.com/",
            "time" : "Thu Sep 03 2015 02:34:04 GMT-0700 (PDT)",
            "useragent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.95 Safari/537.36",
            "responsetime" : 200,
            "pageSize" : 332 
            },{
                "proxy" : "10.0.1.15:1212",
                "url" : "http://www.google.com/in/try",
                "host" : "http://www.google.com/",
                "time" : "Thu Sep 03 2015 02:34:04 GMT-0700 (PDT)",
                "useragent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.95 Safari/537.36",
                "responsetime" : 100,
                "pageSize" : 200 
            },{
                "proxy" : "10.0.1.15:1213",
                "url" : "http://www.google.com/in/demo",
                "host" : "http://www.google.com/",
                "time" : "Thu Sep 03 2015 02:34:04 GMT-0700 (PDT)",
                "useragent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.95 Safari/537.36",
                "responsetime" : 333,
                "pageSize" : 500 

        }];
};


var Chart = React.createClass({  
  getInitialState: function(){
    var state = {
        data : {
            json : getDataFromStores(),
                type : 'line',
                keys : {
                        x: 'url',
                        value: ['proxy', 'url','host','time','responsetime',"pageSize","useragent"]
                    }
        },
        axis : {
            x: {
                type: 'category'
            }
        }
    };
    return state;
  },
  componentDidMount: function(){
    this._renderChart(this.state);
  },
  _renderChart: function(state){
        var lineChart = c3.generate({
        bindto: '#chart_1',
        data: state.data,
        axis: state.axis
    })
  },
  render: function() {
    this._renderChart(this.state);
    return (
      <div id="container">
        <div id="chart_1"></div>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

React.render(<Chart />, document.body);
```

Comment: A note: I recently compiled a list of approaches to d3 vs. react problem, see here: https://gist.github.com/chroth7/a56fafed1efc43737d11 . One core point (of Shirley Wu's article): "D3 should never manipulate what React is already keeping track of.". You find plenty of approaches (from React handles it all to D3 is master of (almost) everything... you're choice! Also, I just added some c3 support to my lib (see in list). Sorry this is not meant to be a promo, I'd rather love to discuss approaches... but stackoverflow is not really meant for a discussion...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach I've taken to use c3 within Reactjs is to to pass in data as properties, and use componentDidUpdate to update the chart. Here's an example. The id stuff is a hack that can be refactored with this.getDOMNode()

```
var GaugeChart = React.createClass({
  propTypes: {
    limit: React.PropTypes.number,
    balance: React.PropTypes.number
  },
  getInitialState: function() {
    return({ id: "" });
  },
  getUUID: function() {
    return 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function(c) {
        var r = Math.random()*16|0, v = c == 'x' ? r : (r&0x3|0x8);
        return v.toString(16);
    });
  },

  renderChart: function() {
    var id = this.state.id;
    var width = 40;
    var self = this;
    (function() {
        self.chart = c3.generate({
        bindto: "#"+self.state.id,
        data: {
          columns: [
            ['Balance', parseFloat(self.props.balance)]
          ],
          type: 'gauge',

        },
        color: {
          pattern: ['#1ca2b8', '#1ca2b8', '#1ca2b8', '#1ca2b8'],
          threshold: {
            values: [30, 60, 90, 100]
          }
        },
        gauge: {
          max: this.props.limit,
          label: {
            format: function (value, ratio) {
              return "$" + value;
            }
          },
          width: width
        },
        tooltip: {
            show: false
        },
        padding: {
          bottom: 20
        }
      });
    })();
    this.update();
  },

  update: function() {
    if (this.chart) {
      this.chart.internal.config.gauge_max = this.props.limit;
      this.chart.load({
          columns: [['Balance', this.props.balance]]
      });
    }
  },

  componentDidMount: function() {
    // hacky way (?) to ensure this always gets it's own id that lasts through the component
    this.setState({id: "gauge-chart-"+this.getUUID()}, this.renderChart);
    $(this.getDOMNode()).on( "resize", this.update );
  },

  componentDidUpdate: function(prevProps, prevState) {
    this.update();
  },

  componentDidDismount: function() {
    $(this.getDOMNode()).off( "resize", this.update );
  },

  render: function() {
    var container = <div id={this.state.id} ></div>
    return container;
  }
});

module.exports = GaugeChart;
```

Hope this is helpful, this approach can be used for resizing the chart as well when the container's size changes.

For connecting to a real time data source you're going to likely have to use websockets, I recommend Socket.io.